# Django HTML Form Send Attachment Emails

Tags: python, html, django, forms, email

I have the following problem using this import

```
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMessage
```

And my code looks something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    email = EmailMessage()
    email.subject = "Test"
    email.body = mainMessage
    email.from_email = "SMTP <XXX@XXX.net>"
    email.to = [ "XXX@XXX.net" ]
    email.attach_file(file)

    email.send()
```

And I check for my file with:

```
if 'file' in request.FILES:
    file = request.FILES['file']
else:
    file = False
```

And this is what my HTML looks like

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'myurl' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="file" name="file" required><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If I choose a file, how can I make it to be sent as an attachment with that email? If I remove `email.attach_file(file)` it works just fine, but only sends the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file']:
    file = request.FILES['file'] 
    if (str(file.content_type) == 'image/jpeg' 
       or str(file.content_type) == 'image/png'):
        if (int(file.size) <= 5000000):
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save('YOUR_DIRECTORY/' + file.name, file)

            email = EmailMessage()
            email.subject = "XXX | Bildupload"
            email.body = mainMessage
            email.from_email = "SMTP <xxx@xxx.net>"
            email.to = ["xxx@xxx.net"]
            email.attach_file(filename)
            email.send()

            answer = 'Die Datei wurde erfolgreich hochgeladen'
            errorAnswer = ''
            return render(request, 'app/hochladen.html', {
                'answer': answer
            })
        else:
            errorAnswer = 'Der Upload hat nicht funktioniert.' 
    else:
        errorAnswer = 'Der Upload hat nicht funktioniert.'
    return render(request, 'app/hochladen.html', {
        'errorAnswer': errorAnswer
    })
```

If anyone is wondering on how to do it, it's possible with the code posted above.
You can delete the second and third if statement, as they check for the size and filetype.

The only answer I've found was to first upload the file to the server, and then access it from there. Although I don't know how to delete it after sending the email and attaching it.

And you need to configure your settings.py correctly and add a /media/ Folder.